# Form Validation with JavaScript and PHP (Not refresh page on submit)

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post, refresh

I am trying to do a form validation with JS that shows feedback as the user types. But of course when submitted the form it's sent using PHP. I already managed to do all of this the only problem I am having now is that when the form is submitted the page refreshes and my "Successfully sent" message cannot be seen. Here is my code and thanks a lot! :D

> HTML FORM

```
<form method="post" id="emailForm" action="?">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="ejemplo@gmail.com" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"/>
                 <p class="alert alert-danger errorEmail"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="María Rodriguez" class="form-control" name="name" id="name"/>
                 <p class="alert alert-danger errorName"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="asunto">Asunto</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Garantía producto" class="form-control" name="asunto" id="asunto" /><span class="badge badgeA"></span>
                 <p class="alert alert-danger errorAsunto"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mensaje">Mensaje</label>
        <textarea placeholder="Ingrese su mensaje aquí, trate de ser lo más claro y conciso posible." name="mensaje" id="mensaje" class="form-control" rows="7"></textarea><span class="badge badgeM"></span>
                 <p class="alert alert-danger errorMensaje"></p>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Enviar!"/>
```

> Field to display feedback of submission

```
<div class="alert alert-success enviado">
</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger noEnviado">
</div>
```

> JavaScript (jQuery)

```
$(function() {

$(".errorEmail").hide();
$(".errorName").hide();
$(".errorAsunto").hide();
$(".errorMensaje").hide();
$(".enviado").hide();
$(".noEnviado").hide();

var error = false;

$('#email').keyup(function(){
    checkEmail();
});

$('#name').keyup(function(){
    checkName();
});

$('#asunto').keyup(function(){
    checkAsunto();
});

$('#mensaje').keyup(function(){
    checkMensaje();
});

function checkEmail() {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    error = false;
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if(re.test(email)) {
        $('.errorEmail').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.errorEmail').html("Ingrese un correo electrónico válido.")
        $('.errorEmail').show();
        error = true;
    }

}

function checkName() {
    var name = $('#name').val().length;
    var minName = 5;
    var cantidad = - (name - minName);
    error = false;
    if (name < 5){
        $('.errorName').html("Por favor ingrese su nombre. <b>Mínimo " + cantidad + " caracteres.</b>");
        $('.errorName').show();
        error = true;
    }
    else {
        $('.errorName').hide();
    }
}

function checkAsunto() {
    var asunto = $('#asunto').val().length;
    var minAsunto = 10;
    var cantidad = - (asunto - minAsunto);
    error = false;
    if (asunto <10){
        $('.errorAsunto').html("Por favor ingrese un asunto.<b> Mínimo " + cantidad + " caracteres.</b>");
        $('.errorAsunto').show();
        error = true;
    }
    else {
        $('.errorAsunto').hide();
    }
}

function checkMensaje() {
    var email = $('#mensaje').val().length;
    var minMensaje = 20;
    var cantidad = - (email - minMensaje);
    error = false;
    if (email < 20){
        $('.errorMensaje').html("Por favor ingrese un mensaje. <b> Mínimo " + cantidad + " caracteres. </b>");
        $('.errorMensaje').show();
        error = true;
    }
    else {
        $('.errorMensaje').hide();
    }
}

$('#emailForm').submit( function() {            
    checkEmail();
    checkName();
    checkAsunto();
    checkMensaje();

    if(error === false) {
        $('.enviado').html("Mensaje enviado exitosamente");
        $('.enviado').fadeIn(500);
        $('.noEnviado').fadeOut(500);
        return true;


    } else {
        $('.noEnviado').html("Ups... hubo un problema");
        $('.noEnviado').fadeIn(500);
        $('.enviado').fadeOut(500);
        return false;

    }
});
```

});

> PHP

The PHP code is really simple some how it doesn't let me display it here but it just get's the $_POST values on the form and sends them using email();

Thanks guys

Comment: Don't post back to the same page. If you want to remain on the same page, use AJAX. I'm downvoting this as there's too many solutions you can choose from.

Comment: Maybe you could have enlightening me with one of the many solutions, but thanks anyway.

Comment: No. This would involve too much code and has nothing to do with how you've asked the question. It is one solution. Your question is too broad. Stack overflow is not meant to be used to outsource broad solutions. You must provide a question that is specific. I have given you a heads up on what you should be doing. You should have done that and removed the question, then reposted something more specific if you got stuck and the question didn't already exist on SO. It is also a bit annoying that someone answers with pretty much my comment, and you select it as the answer. It is not an answer.

Comment: Alright there, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning true replace it with an Ajax post request to the same script, on success show the message you wish.

Comment: I'll try that, im not really experienced with AJAX yet. Thanks :D

Comment: When I get home I'll help u more

Comment: I appreciate it a lot! Thank you